# Can't use JNI to call a dll method

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface

I try to write a wrapper for the CDRip library. But I'm very new in JNI. I have a problem to get a native method to work:

```
public class CDRipJNI {
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("CDRip");
  }

  // Get the DLL version number
  static native int CR_GetCDRipVersion();
}
```

In another class I call this method:

```
int version = CDRipJNI.CR_GetCDRipVersion();
```

The dll is loaded successfully but the method call fails:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.test.CDRipJNI.CR_GetCDRipVersion()J
    at com.test.CDRipJNI.CR_GetCDRipVersion(Native Method)
    at Test.main(Test.java:5)
```

Comment: Does it have such a method? Is it a JNI DLL?

Comment: Yes, the method exists, has this signature and is exported. I think the dll is written with C++.

Comment: No, it has a C signature with the word 'Java' in it: what is that? Should be `JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_test_CDRipJNI_CR_1GetCDRipVersion
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);`

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure that I understand this.

Comment: If it's a JNI DLL it will have C methods with signatures dictated by the `javah` tool. If it doesn't have that signature, which it clearly doesn't, either your Java class is wrong or it isn't a JNI DLL at all. Curious if it *is* a JNI DLL why you would have to write any kind of wrapper for it at all: they should provide it. And if it isn't a JNI DLL *you* wil have to write one that calls it.

Comment: So if it's not a JNI dll, then I have no chance to call the methods from this library?

Comment: Yes, see my last sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it doesn't have a method with that signature, which it doesn't, either your Java class is wrong or it isn't a JNI DLL at all.

If it *is* a JNI DLL, I don't know why you would have to write any kind of wrapper for it at all: they should provide it.

So it isn't. And if it isn't a JNI DLL, you wil have to write your own JNI DLL that calls it, and that matches your Java class, etc. etc. as per usual JNI.

Comment: Ah ok you mean that I have to write my own dll which contains JNI named methods and internally call the methods from the other dll?